# Loop (ngfor) who to set a "position"

Tags: angular, loops, ngfor, ionic4

I would like to start my loop at a position 4, by example

There is the code :

```
    <ion-slides>        
      <ion-slide  *ngFor="let img of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">
        <img src="{{img}}.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

I really don't know how to do

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-slides>        
      <ion-slide  *ngFor="let img of images [options]="opts">
        <img src="{{img}}.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
  @Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/test/test.html',
})

export class TestPage implements OnInit{
    images= [1,2,3];
    opts: any;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
            this.opts = {initialSlide: 5}
    }

}
```

Comment: When i do this, it take of the 1, 2, 3 ,4 in the array and i don't want that. I want to start at number 4 but the slide can go to 3 or 5.... I hope you're understand what i say :D

Comment: oh you want to just be able to start at the fourth picture but still be able to slide back and forth? Check my update

Comment: Yes exactly ! I try to read how to use initialSlide but i found nothing. I'm new in programming. Can you give me more detail about how to write the code ? Thanks a lot Flash

Comment: it should just be In  `<ion-slides [intitialSlide]="5">`

Comment: or  `<ion-slides [options] ="opts"`  then in your ts. file `ngOnInit() {
this.opts = {initialSlide: 2, pager: true}
}`

Comment: when i do <ion-slides [initialSlide]="5"> i get this error message:  Can't bind to 'intitialSlide' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-slides'

Comment: it looks like it't supposed to be passed through the options and then defined in you component. did they other option work?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad knowledge, i'm reading to find how you declare "opts" in the ts file because I have the message: Property 'Opts' does not exist on type ...

Comment: Check the update

Comment: Your second way work! but I get this error message because i don't define "Opts" correctly i think:    [ng] ERROR in album.page.ts: Type '{ initialSlide: number; pager: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
[ng]   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'initialSlide' does not exist in type 'any[]'.

Comment: sorry you may have to define it as an object  like this: `opts: object ` are you using a service?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a method in component that will slice an array:

your template code:

```
    <ion-slides>        
      <ion-slide  *ngFor="let img of (sliceImages([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]))">
        <img src="{{img}}.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

your component code:

```
sliceImages(array: number[]): number[] {
    return array.slice(4);
}
```

An alternative way is [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe):

your template code:

```
    <ion-slides>        
      <ion-slide  *ngFor="let img of ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] | slice : 4)">
        <img src="{{img}}.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Thanks !! But the slice kill the 4 first img :(

Answer (score 1):

@Flash Thank you very much for your help !!

there is the code i did :

xxx.page.ts:

```
    export class AlbumPage implements OnInit {

      opts: object;

      imageArray = [
        '027A0200', '027A1238', '027A1399',
        '027A1543', '027A1905', '027A2103',
        '027A2344', '027A2503', '027A2529',
        '027A2557', '027A2591', '027A2605',
        '027A2670', '027A2728', '027A2770',
        '027A2885', '027A2995', '027A3010',
        '027A3018', '027A3106'
      ];

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.opts = {
          initialSlide: 3,
          pager: true
        };
      }

    }
```

xxx.page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <div>
    <ion-slides [options] ="opts">        
      <ion-slide  *ngFor="let img of imageArray">
        <img src="../../../assets/Album/{{img}}.jpg" >
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked!! :) I checked ! Thanks again Flash